# Why $(n \times Id )_* O_{A\times A^\vee} = \oplus_{\tau \in A^\vee(S)} (Id\times \tau \circ \pi^\vee)^*P$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider an abelian scheme  $\pi: A\rightarrow S$, with dual abelian scheme $\pi^\vee: A^\vee\rightarrow S$. The paper I am reading proved a lemma saying that $[n]_* O_A = \oplus_{\mu \in A^\vee[n](S)} \mu$. We identify points of $A^\vee[n](S)$ with line bundles on $A$ by pulling back the Poincare bundle to $A\times_S S = A$.

Then it says that $(n \times Id )_* O_{A\times A^\vee} = \oplus_{\tau \in A^\vee(S)} (Id\times \tau \circ \pi^\vee)^*P$ where $P$ is the Poincare bundle on $A\times_S A^\vee$. I suppose that they are applying the lemma to the abelian scheme $A\times_S A^\vee \rightarrow A^\vee$, and the multiplication by $n$ map becomes $[n]\times Id$, but I don't understand why the $n$ disappear on the right hand side of the second statement. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What's the paper?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there must be a typo, and the sum should be the same as your lemma has it, i.e. over $A^\vee[n](S)$. For one thing, if $S$ is the spectrum of an algebraically closed field, without the $n$ one otherwise ends up with an infinite sum as $\tau$ ranges over the entire $A^\vee(S)$.

In any event, as you say, one has $ ( 1 \times_S \tau )^* P = \tau$, if the $\tau$ on the left of the equal sign is viewed as $\tau \in A^\vee(S)=\hom_S( S, A^\vee) $, and the $\tau$ on the right is viewed as the corresponding line bundle on $A \times_S S = A$. So, substituting into the original lemma, one has
$$  n_∗\,O_A=\oplus_{\tau\in A^\vee[n](S)} (1 \times_S \tau)^* P. $$ 
 Pulling back by $ 1 \times_S \pi^\vee$, we get 
$$  (1 \times_S \pi^\vee)^* n_*\,O_A=\oplus_{\tau\in A^\vee[n](S)}(1 \times_S \pi^\vee)^* (1 \times_S \tau)^* P, $$ 
so that 
$$(n \times_S 1 )_*\, O_{A\times_S A^\vee} = \oplus_{\tau \in A^\vee[n](S)} (1\times_S (\tau \circ \pi^\vee))^*P.$$